# HttpException not being caught

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2005, iis-6

I have this exception:

```
Server Error in '/datalab' Application.

Request timed out.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]
```

But I added a Global.asax file to my /datalab and /datalab/powerstats directories (the datalab directory is the root while the page being timed out is datalab/powerstats/output.aspx):

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">



void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

  // Handle HTTP errors
  if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
  {
  Response.Write("<h2>Global Page Error</h2>\n");

        // The Complete Error Handling Example generates
        // some errors using URLs with "NoCatch" in them;
        // ignore these here to simulate what would happen
        // if a global.asax handler were not implemented.
        if (exc.Message.Contains("NoCatch") || exc.Message.Contains("maxUrlLength"))
            return;

        //Redirect HTTP errors to HttpError page
        //Server.Transfer("HttpErrorPage.aspx");
        return;
    }


}



</script>
```

How do I catch this exception? Why isn't it being caought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Application_Error` event is called when an unhandled exception occurs.

You can't then go back and change the response as an Internal Server Error 500 response has already been sent to the client.

The answer to your problem is to fix the reason for the timeout, or to increase the timeout period programmatically. To do this in the web.config try adding:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="<numOfSeconds>" />
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: umm okay so but why isn't it being grabbed anywher

Comment: Can you give more information/code relating to the datalab/powerstats/output.aspx page?

Comment: The output page has a Page__Load that calls RunTable() function that fires off a stored procedure. By doing it in 2 separate browsers, one works and the other gives the timed out error.

Comment: Seems like one of the threads hangs since the db is way too busy processing my statistics code. So the db gets busy and the page seems to hang. Since I can't lower the db processing, how do I force my page to throw an exception that I can catch

Comment: You can't, just increase the length of time before the exception is thrown.

Comment: Yeah but that might put a load on the server?

Comment: If you can reduce the time the the stored procedure takes that would be best. The server load won't be high but the number of concurrent request it can handle will be lowered until you can improve performance of the stored procedure - that would be a separate question.

Comment: The stored procedure is an extremely complicated statistics package that is called and runs in a sql assembly, its a no go and reducing that

Comment: any idea on a redirect after timeout is exceeded in the web.config? is custom errors the only way?

Comment: Yes custom errors, but it would have to be a generic redirect for any unhandled exception.

Comment: that sucks, then no other way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16062/discussion-between-spolto-and-chris)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used stack tracing before?

Look up MSDN documentation on how to use them. They have different type of stack trace depending on your application.